# Send javamail using Office365

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, office365

I'm having trouble configuring the SMTP settings for sending mail using `javax.mail (1.4.4)` through Office365, so I thought I'd post the properties here for others.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Office365 smtp details as below:

> ```
> private static Properties props;  
> private static Session session;   
> static {      
>   props = new Properties();
>   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
>   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
>   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "m.outlook.com");
>   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");        
>   session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {          
>       @Override
>       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
>           return new PasswordAuthentication("office365 email address",
>                   "office365 password");          
>       }       
>   });
>
> }
> ```

Comment: The problem I am facing is my thread got stuck before sending mail, I tried many solutions from internet non of them worked, I don't get any exception too. I am unable to send mail, it would be helpful if you share your knowledge.. :) thanks

Comment: For me, this only worked after I changed `587` to `"587"`. Otherwise, JavaMail tried to connect over port 25.

Comment: It would be better if the code in this answer were to use [setProperty(String, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), this way you don't run into the problem @Glorfindel describes. Also, the Authenticator is not necessary if you use `transport.sendMessage(...)` on a `Transport` instance for which you called `connect(server, user, password)` first.

Comment: I'm also facing thread stuck issue:

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false

Comment: @JBert : how can we create an instance transport of the abstract class Transport? Should we create a new child class?I have an issue with smtp.office365.com (Unknown server) and I'd like to separate connection and authentification from sending - as a debug. So your proposition to call connect() is interesting for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you so so much! This fixed my thread stuck issue. How the hell can this happen?

Comment: After `AUTH LOGIN` error occour: `535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. ` 2023

Answer (score 11):

And with spring-boot, you simply need to add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.username = mathieu.pousse@headquarter.com
spring.mail.password = s3cr3t
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
```

Answer (score 4):

A working code example:

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();

email.setHostName("smtp.office365.com");
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("a@b.com", "****"));
email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
try {
    email.setFrom("a@b.com");
    email.setSubject("Job Failure");
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)" );
    email.addTo("a@y.com");
    email.send();
} catch (EmailException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You might want to specify that this uses [commons-email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/).

Answer (score 0):

The only error that I am noticing in your code is the incorrect Host

```
javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.from", "abc@c.com");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user",  "abc@c.com");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password","Password");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Change the host you will be all good.