# I need to send emails from an email hosted on a Microsoft Exchange server

Tags: java, email, smtp, exchange-server

I successfully created a java program that can send emails from a gmail account, however, now I need to do the same with an email account using a Microsoft Exchange Server.

The difference is when I was creating the gmail application I had all the information I needed to just plug into the JavaMail API program to make it work. For example, the SMTP server is smtp.gmail.com, the port is 587, the account needs to be set to "Less secure login requirements", etc...

I do not have access to any of this information for the Exchange Server. I am wondering if this is possible to do? I would assume I probably wont be able to use the JavaMail API like I did with gmail seeing as i don't have any of the information that is required for the fields. Is there some other library out there that I can use?

If some of this sounds like I don't really know what I'm talking about it's probably because I don't. This is kind of new territory for me, and I seem to have hit a wall. Basically I just need a program that can send an email from an account hosted on a Microsoft Exchange server. Hopefully this make since. Thanks.

Comment: The place to start would be to determine what access to the Mailbox does the hosting provider provide. Eg if the provide you with IMAP access to the mailbox then using port 587 (default SMTP port for IMAP) eg Office365 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430962/send-javamail-using-office365

Answer (score 1):

Ms Exchange and GMail are both email providers, they rely on the same protocol : [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). So your JavaMail API should also work with Exchange, provided the required features are enabled :

1. SMTP : should be enabled by default, unless your admin disabled it.
2. [SMTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication), or [SMTP relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay) for your sender IP address : Some authentication mechanisms (AUTH LOGIN) are disabled by default on latest versions of Exchange. Relay also has to be configured by the admin.

The easiest way to find out your exchange server address and port is to contact your Exchange administrator. However, you can find it by yourself by :

1. If you're not on the exchange local network, you can try "nslookup -q=mx senderdomain.com" to find out the Exchange IP adderss
2. Else, you can try and follow [this procedure](http://support.dataviz.com/support.srch?docid=13629)

Once you have the Exchange IP address, confirm that SMTP delivery port (25) is opened, it should be. If relay is authorized for your IP, you should be done.
Else, test if SMTP submission port (587) is opened, that should be the one you use to send authenticated emails.

Alternatively, you can try and use [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) API, provided it's enabled on the server. There seems to be a Microsoft JAVA libray to use EWS : [ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api).