# How to send email from within my Android app?

Tags: java, android, email

I am making an educational Android app and I wished the users to send report E-mails if they find the app crashing or some wrong data has been provided or anything like that.

So what I've come to know is that we can send an E-mail from the app using this `Intent`:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");
```

But I wish to send an E-mail from within my app and I don't want to use `Intent` to send E-mail from other apps like G-mail, Outlook, etc. I just want to send an email directly to my G-mail account, i.e., `gouravkhunger18@gmail.com`.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241474/android-app-development-send-email-directly-with-no-intents

Answer (score 2):

I tried different ways and I did a lot of research and I tell you my experience:

Firstly, you will have 3 ways to send your email:

Use java api

Use phpMailer

Use of mass mailing companies

To use java api, you can find and use many projects on the Internet.

To use phpMailer first get download phpMailer :

[getPhpMailer](http://I%20tried%20different%20ways%20and%20I%20did%20a%20lot%20of%20research%20and%20I%20tell%20you%20my%20experience:%20Firstly,%20you%20will%20have%203%20ways%20to%20send%20your%20email:%20Use%20java%20api%20Use%20phpMailer%20Use%20of%20mass%20mailing%20companies%20To%20use%20java%20api,%20you%20can%20find%20and%20use%20many%20projects%20on%20the%20Internet.%20Login%20to%20use%20phpMailer%20first:%20https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Now open phpMailer and match your project.
To use phpMailer, I recommend that you do not try on localhost because it is very troublesome and you can try your own hosting.

and for mass mailing , You can use many companies for example try [Mail Chimp](https://mailchimp.com/?&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImfaSuIGs3QIVo7XtCh12qwpzEAAYASAAEgKQTfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

I personally use the third one and I suggest not using java api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous answer source code, but if you are using a Gmail account, it will block the connection because of security issues. I recommend you to get a cheap hosting whit a CPanel. With CPanel, you can easily create email accounts and use it for sending emails unlimitedly.

Comment: I think It's a comment more than an answer!